# How to create an email interceptor between Gmail accounts

Tags: api, email, interceptor

This is the project we have.  We send an email, through some email service to client1 with a specific return address.  They reply via Gmail or whatever, and that hits our email service and is forwarded to our api.  We process that email and then forward it on to client2.

This way we stand in between two Gmail accounts let's say, so they can have a conversation without actually seeing each other's email address.

Furthermore, we need to be able to keep these emails threaded, so when client1 replies via Gmail, there is something in the header that can be recognized by our api as a thread id and forwarded with the email to the client2.  When client2 replies it will hit our api and have that id in the header somewhere.

The problem we are finding is that

a) Gmail will strip out custom headers
b) when we forward the message to client 2 it's seen as a new initial message and thus given a new messageId and no in-reply-to id.

Is there a service or a process that can do this?

Comment: A lot of systems embed the reply `id` in the body of the message somewhere that is parseable. The thing is, if the email is not quoted and headers are stripped I'm at a bit of a loss. You could try something with the email address. Gmail allows you to use the '+' so `spam+johndoe@gmail.com` still directs to `johndoe@gmail.com`

Comment: interesting.  a) i've been doing a lot of research and have not come across that little secret, where did you find it? b) would the client see "spam+johndoe@gmail.com" or would they just see "johndoe@gmail.com" and c) do you think other email clients (yahoo, hotmail) would do that too?

Comment: Ticketing systems use the body embed I think, and it would show up including the + unfortunately, I don't know about the other clients.. You could use a combination of header\body embed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@SamV had some good suggestions.  However I found a company that handles this pretty well, called mailgun, they allow you to create your own initial message-id and they persist your in-reply-to id when you forward your message to the final endpoint. I think.  I haven't done the poc yet but they say they do.